Romans 3:22 – ‘of’ or ‘in’? Old translations differ from modern ones. Why?
Tyndale’s English translation of 1525 – The rightewesnes no dout which is good before God, commeth by the fayth of Jesus Christ’
The Great Bible of 1539 – ‘The ryghtewesnes of God, commeth by the fayth of Jesus Christ’
The Geneva Bible of 1560 – ‘(To wit,) the righteousnes of God commeth by the faith of Jesus Christ’
The Catholic Rheims Version of 1582, ‘And the justice of God by faith of Jesus Christ’
The King James of 1611, - ‘Even the righteousness of God which is by faith of Jesus Christ’
Young’s Literal Translation of 1898 – ‘and the righteousness of God [is] through the faith of Jesus Christ’
The Companion Bible of 1922 – ‘Even the righteousness of God [which is] by faith of Jesus Christ’
The Revised Version (of the Authorised version) of 1881 – ‘Even the righteousness of God through faith in Jesus Christ’
The Revised Standard Version of 1946 – ‘The righteousness of God through faith in Jesus Christ’
The New American Standard Bible of 1960 - ‘even the righteousness of God through faith in Jesus Christ’
The New English Bible of 1961 – ‘It is God’s way of righting wrong, effective through faith in Christ’
The Good News Bible of 1976 – ‘God puts people right through their faith in Jesus Christ’
The New International Version of 1987 – ‘This righteousness from God comes through faith in Jesus Christ’
The New Living Translation of 2008 – ‘We are made right with God by placing our faith in Jesus Christ’
Apparently, the Greek text is not contested. Manuscripts show the Greek for ‘of’, with none saying ‘in’. This is the accepted Greek text: δικαιοσύνη δὲ θεοῦ διὰ πίστεως Ἰησοῦ Χριστοῦ  The preposition is not ἐν, but δua. The case is genitive, so it cannot read ‘in’. Note also that the same changes in modern translations occur in Galatians 2:16 & 20, so this is not a one-of slip-up.
What reasons could there be for this subtle but profound change from ‘of’ to ‘in’?
I suspect a clue lies in the non-literal NEB, GNB and NLT above. If so, what would that indicate as to possible motive for such changes?
EDIT in response to similar Q link - That Q wants answers to what "faith in" means. My Q wants to compare that with what "faith of" means, and why the Greek text that clearly says "faith of" appears to be ignored in modern translations.

Related: What does "faith in Jesus Christ" mean in Romans 3:22?

This concerns the translation of the genitive which has an extremely versatile meaning in Greek.  Grammatically, "Faithfulness of Jesus" and "faith in Jesus" are both possible, but the former is more grammatically correct.  In short, "faith" is not a work we do to earn salvation - we are saved by the faithfulness of Jesus. Any faith we have is initiated by God.  Put another way, we trust Jesus to be trustworthy.

Many versions are translated by groups whose theology demands that we are saved by our faith in Jesus and thus present our faith as a word we perform to become saved.  The Bible is clear that we are saved by the drawing of God via the Holy Spirit - salvation is not partly human.  Faith is simply the hand that accepts the faithfulness and trustworthiness of Jesus in saving us.  I agree with Mike below that "faith of Jesus" meaning the faith in the trustworthiness/faithfulness of Jesus is the best translation.

Language changes over time.

I can see similarities in this to the other, previous question but this question is specifically dealing with a variety of translations and is attempting to clear the rendering across all these translations. I think the question should stand and it has received very good response so far, and I have to say, unusually, unanimous agreement (thus far).

One receives Jesus, "But as many as received him, to them gave he power to become the sons of God, even to them that believe on his name (John 1:12)", the true light that gives life, and in that turning from what one is (utterly sinful) unto Jesus (what one should be) one is born again. The power to become sons of God, then, is the very faith of Christ. This faith is the fruit of the Spirit and it is born within one by the indwelling Spirit. Without this faith of Christ within no one may please God. It is Christ in us (literally) the hope of glory.

Justification is a much misunderstood doctrine and, as a result, some have struggled to translate the very precise wording of, particularly, the apostle Paul who wrote some things, as Peter puts it, 'hard to be understood' which some 'wrest', misrepresenting what he said and wrote.
Particularly, there is misappropriation of prepositions, it is evident.

Romans 3:22 (TR undisputed) :

δικαιοσυνη δε θεου δια πιστεως ιησου χριστου εις παντας και επι παντας τους πιστευοντας ου γαρ εστιν διαστολη


Righteousness of God through faith of Jesus Christ unto all and upon all those believing  (see EGNT and Biblehub)

The Righteousness of God himself is unto all (not within, not magically appropriated into) and upon all (again, not intrinsically derived inside) those believing (not that once made a decision, not that assert a creed but those actively believing).
The faith that is of Jesus Christ results in Righteousness being unto them and upon them who are also believing.
It is his faith and it has an outcome towards the believing.

This same construction is seen in Philippians 3:9 (TR) :

εχων εμην δικαιοσυνην την εκ νομου αλλα την δια πιστεως χριστου την εκ θεου δικαιοσυνην επι τη πιστει


not ... mine own righteousness that of law but that through faith of Christ the out of God righteousness upon the faith  (see EGNT and Biblehub)

Again righteousness is out of God (ek) and is upon (epi) the faith (not inside, not within, not blended into . . . . .  'upon').

The same is seen in Romans 1:17 (TR)

δικαιοσυνη γαρ θεου εν αυτω αποκαλυπτεται εκ πιστεως εις πιστιν καθως γεγραπται ο δε δικαιος εκ πιστεως ζησεται


... righteousness for of God in it (the gospel) is revealed out of faith unto faith according is written 'but the just out of faith shall live'

Out of faith (of Jesus Christ) unto faith (of the believing).
For the justified (the just) out of faith . . . . .  shall live.

Believing that God would redeem his people through his own vicarious efficacy, Jesus showed faith in going to Jerusalem in such a dangerous time, for him as an individual. He showed faith among his brethren, the disciples, encouraging them despite the worsening persecution and threat. He showed faith at the supper, prophesying and encouraging and preparing the way for them after his death.
He showed faith in Gethsemane, perspiration dripping from him, the way droplets of blood drop down, an angel from heaven granting his humanity strength in the inner conflict. He showed faith in allowing the disciples to go free while he was taken.
Faith on the Via Dolorosa ; faith when affixed to the wood of the cross ; faith towards a penitent thief ; faith towards God almighty, though he was forsaken ; faith to cry out 'It is finished !'.
And faith to yield up his life (none taking it from him).
Oh what faith was demonstrated by Jesus Christ as the Righteousness of God was demonstrated upon him - upon sins within his body (not his own sins) and upon the humanity 'made sin' that the clean may take the sin of the world away in death on the behalf of the unclean.
Oh what faith was demonstrated by Jesus Christ !

Note after Comment :
The penitent sinner sees the Righteousness of God being demonstrated upon his own Son, against the actual sins committed ('who bore our sins in his body on the tree') thus the sufferings of Christ prior to his death ; and against his own fallen human nature ('he was made sin for us who knew no sin') thus his giving up his life in death.
Seeing this, the believer trusts in God, trusting in the Righteousness of God and the effective judgment upon his own sins and sin, and believes in  Jesus Christ in respect of his own justification.
God, seeing this faith in the believer, sees within that faith, His Own Righteousness and evaluates that righteousness unto the believer.
It would be unrighteous not to do so.
Thus, is that righteousness upon the believer, without the law and without the deeds of the law.
It is not a legal righteousness : it is Divine Righteousness.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Scholars word the question as:  "Is διὰ πίστεως Ἰησοῦ Χριστοῦ (Literally, "through faith/faithfulness of Jesus Christ") an objective or subjective genitive?  So, objective versus subjective is the issue.
Objective genitive presents Christ Jesus as the object of the faith.
Subjective genitive presents Christ Jesus as the one doing the faith (ie. the subject of the verbal idea of faith/faithfulness).
If it's objective genitive, then the best English rendering is "through faith in Jesus Christ".
If it's subjective genitive, then the best English rendering is  "through the faithfulness of Jesus Christ."
Now, what if you're a Bible translator and you don't want to make a choice between those two?  Well, you use the ambiguous word 'of', which allows for both interpretations.
And that's basically the answer to your question.  As far as motive goes, it's dangerous to impute motives, especially anything suggesting maliciousness.  I've known several Bible translators, I've met hundreds involved in Bible translation work, they are all fantastic people.  The answer to the "why the 'of'" question is this: the 'of' is ambiguous and the Greek genitive ambiguous.  So, ironically, 'of' is the more literally, verbally accurate translation. Though I think the meaning is clear enough, see below.
For a fuller answer, a Greek language analysis won't help you.  The Greek really is ambiguous between the two types of genitives (with English providing the ambiguous way to render the ambiguous Greek--that is, using 'of').
So, for a fuller answer, one has to exegete Paul's argument from Romans 1:17 through to 3:31.  Verse 1:17 is the "from faith to faith" verse (ἐκ πίστεως εἰς πίστιν).  And the last paragraph of chapter 3 is Paul introducing what Christ has done.
My opinion?  I believe it's a subjective genitive.  At the beginning of Paul's treatise, he states that, from beginning to end, through and through, righteousness is obtained solely by faith (πίστις) (verse 1:17).  After Paul shows that all people, no matter what ethnicity they are, are within the dominion of sin and the wrath of God, he introduces that the solution is Christ Jesus who, himself, was the faithful one.  Faith (ie πίστις) is what is required--in all cases.  Christ did exactly that.  And he did it in our place.  Paul will, in a few chapters (see chapter 7), cry out in utter, complete hopelessness, "Who can save me from this body of death?," having showed that he, himself, had been conned (ἐξαπατάω, verse 7:11) by sin into thinking he could achieve righteousness himself.  He coveted righteousness for himself which broke the law.  Sin, using the Law, locked him into a catch-22 situation where if he pursued righteousness for himself, he broke the law; and if he didn't, he broke the law.  "Who can save me??!!!"  He answers that Jesus Christ has done the solution, and therefore, there is "now no condemnation."  It's all Christ!
Also, taking the phrase διὰ πίστεως Ἰησοῦ Χριστοῦ as subjective genitive explains the phrase that immediately follows it, εἰς πάντας τοὺς πιστεύοντας (Literally, "into all the believers").  Believers are here presented as those who receive that which has just been stated by the previous phrase.  I don't know what "God's righteousness through believing in Jesus Christ unto all the believers" could mean.  But, "God's righteousness through Jesus Christ's faithfulness unto all the believers" makes sense to me (though I think the meaning could be stated in English a little better).  Simply, the meaning is:  I've greatly benefited, as a believer, by Christ being faithful to God's requirements that he was called to do.  It's all grace!
So, that's how the argument goes, and so I think the subjective genitive best supports that flow of thought.

Would it have been hard for the greek to be clear?   So was it chosen to write it this way to it give it both meanings?

@IanRingrose Both meanings is certainly an interpretation that is offered.  I think the follow-on phrase doesn't make sense with the one meaning (see my answer).  As far as ambiguity goes, any language--in a small text (phrase)--is ambiguous.  And, an author will attempt to make it clear--in a big text (paragraph).  So, I think Rom 3:21-26 clarifies the phrase.  Note that 3:26 ends with ἐκ πίστεως Ἰησοῦ (out of faith of Jesus).  I would think of that in English as, "supplied by Jesus' faith."  So, Paul is clarifying (ie restating) his point. Think this:  what does the paragraph mean?

“the ambiguous word 'of', which allows for both interpretations.”  Does it today?  It may well have done, back in the time of Early Modern English translations such as the KJV.  But to my ears, ‘of’ very strongly indicates your second case, and it would need some linguistic gymnastics to fit the first.  (I note that your explanation of the two cases uses ‘of’ in only the second.)  If so, then maybe modern translators can't render the ambiguity intact, and so are forced to decide between the two cases?

@gidds  Your point is quite valid. I had thought to clarify that point, and didn't.  The Greek genitive is the kind-of case.  The English 'of', at least according to the Oxford Dictionary, can mean "typical or characteristic of".  And it offers: "She has the face of an angel."  That is, an angelic kind of face.  To the average Christian, what is referred to when one talks about "a faith that is the Christ Jesus kind of faith"?  Faith in Christ.  That's the linguistic gymnastics (I've used "semantic gymnastics" :-) )  Translators are always forced to choose across multiple semantic domains.

It is a really good question.  The faith "of" Christ is in reference to having faith in the righteousness of God (through Christ).  We have faith in His righteousness as being our righteousness, being imputed to us upon having that faith (Romans 4).  If "faith of Christ" is changed to "faith in Christ", then the righteousness of God, performed on our behalf through Christ, could be easily overlooked...causing one to believe that God's requirement of righteousness remains to be the burden of the believer (making them to be a non-believer in actuality).  I will admit that I cannot answer definitively as to "why" it was changed, but if scripture serves us here, I do believe the purpose was more sinister than just a one-off error, as you also stated.
Ephesians 6:12

For we wrestle not against flesh and blood, but against principalities, against powers, against the rulers of the darkness of this world, against spiritual wickedness in high places.

Romans 10:1-4

Brethren, my heart's desire and prayer to God for Israel is, that they might be saved.
2 For I bear them record that they have a zeal of God, but not according to knowledge.
3 For they being ignorant of God's righteousness, and going about to establish their own righteousness, have not submitted themselves unto the righteousness of God.
4 For Christ is the end of the law for righteousness to every one that believeth.


This question is likely to be closed because it is a duplicate.  However, the matter raised in Rom 3:22 is common to a series of other verses which I will list for completeness only.
The texts listed below should be read in the context that salvation is entirely the initiative of God and that man’s (positive) response is due to God’s prompting (Phil 2:13, John 6:44, Rom 2:4, John 12:32, 1 Cor 12:3; repentance is also a gift Acts 5:31, 11:18, 2 Tim 2:25), but this does not preclude the possibility that a person can reject the prompting and pleading of the Holy Spirit (Acts 7:51, 1 Thess 5:19, Eph 4:30).
πίστεως Ἰησοῦ Χριστοῦ = Faithfulness of Jesus Christ

Rom 3:22 - And this righteousness from God comes through faithfulness of Jesus Christ to all who believe/trust/have faith.
Rom 3:26 - He did this to demonstrate His righteousness at the present time, so as to be just and to justify the one of faithfulness of Jesus.
Gal 2:16 - know that a man is not justified by works of the law, but by faithfulness of Jesus Christ. So we, too, have believed in Christ Jesus, that we may be justified by faithfulness of Christ and not by works of the law, because by works of the law no one will be justified.
Gal 3:22 - But the Scripture pronounces all things confined by sin, so that by faithfulness of Jesus Christ the promise might be given to those who trust/believe/have faith.
Rev 14:12 - Here is a call for the perseverance of the saints who keep the commandments of God and the faithfulness of Jesus.

πίστιν θεοῦ = faithfulness of God

Mark 11:22 - And Jesus answering, says to them, "Have faithfulness of God.
Rom 3:3 - What if indeed some disbelieved? Will their unbelief nullify the faithfulness of God?

πίστεως ἐν Χριστῷ Ἰησοῦ = Faith/Trust in Christ Jesus
The New Testament also contains the phrase “faith/trust in Jesus” (“pistis en Iesous”) and in all cases the phrase is used as the basis for the Christian life and/or a cause for celebration and note by others.  Gal 3:26, Eph 1:15, Col 1:4, 1 Tim 1:14, 3:13, 2 Tim 1:13, 3:15, Heb 11:6

Consider the issue from the perspective of righteousness:

even the righteousness of God, through faith in Jesus Christ, to all and on all who believe. For there is no difference (ESV)
δικαιοσύνη δὲ θεοῦ διὰ πίστεως Ἰησοῦ Χριστοῦ εἰς πάντας τοὺς πιστεύοντας οὐ γάρ ἐστιν διαστολή

Is the righteousness Paul speaks of God or is the righteousness in God? To answer consider if Paul had left out God and written only δικαιοσύνη δὲ διὰ πίστεως. This would describe "any" righteousness through faith, and as Paul is writing about what God has done, God is implied δικαιοσύνη δὲ [θεοῦ] διὰ πίστεως. However, Paul is not content to let the reader understand by implication, and so he wants to restrict what the reader is to understand about righteousness.
There are different ways Paul has to restrict the meaning of righteousness. For example Paul could have written δικαιοσύνη δὲ ἀπὸ θεοῦ even righteousness from God. Omitting the preposition ἀπὸ in δικαιοσύνη δὲ θεοῦ does not mean the righteousness is not from God. The difference between the two phrases is the addition of ἀπὸ restricts more than just θεοῦ. In other words, the genitive θεοῦ restricts by removing all meaning which  is not θεοῦ. It leaves in place from, of, in, with and so forth.
The issue in translating into English is two-fold. First, English does not have a comparable case. Second, English does not have one word which means from, of, in, with. English does not have a simple method to describe partial restrictions. English would say from God because of God is ambiguous. Greek conceptualizes restrictions differently. To say we must decide whether the genitive is subjective or objective is to impose a level of specificity Paul never intended.
Righteousness θεοῦ is inherently from God, of God, in God, with God. The genitive θεοῦ only filters out anything which is not consistent with θεός.
This should not be confused as being ambiguous. There is no ambiguity in the Greek, because the genitive conceptualizes by removing all that is not consistent with "God." The ability to interpret the genitive more than one way, is a consequence of the limitation of the English language. Where the Greek genitive specifically "filters out" what is not from God, English requires further distillation: there can only be one. Since a translator lacks a single word, the original phrase which encompasses everything of God, is expressed more narrowly than the Paul intended.
The same is true with faith. διὰ πίστεως Ἰησοῦ Χριστοῦ means through [all] faith Jesus Christ. A choice between "of" or "in" is artificial. In the Greek, one is impossible without the other.

This is a great explanation. Although the English language does not have one word which encompasses from, of, in, with, faith from or of is very different than faith in or with. Paul uses both in and of here, implying a distinction: Gal 2:16 "Knowing that a man is not justified by the works of the law, but by the faith of Jesus Christ, even we have believed in Jesus Christ, that we might be justified by the faith of Christ, and not by the works of the law: for by the works of the law shall no flesh be justified."  We believe in Christ and are justified by the faith of Christ.

@MarkVestal Thank you. I do not disagree with what you say. But I think the meaning begins with the statement in question. That is, those in Rome are not going to get the letter to the Galatians in order to form an understanding of what was written to them. Rather, they are going to establish the foundation of righteousness by faith on the basis of what was written to them. Certainly the two should be understood collectively yet the individual must first stand on its own.
